# create db,table and insert data and retrieve it in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android.
Can anyone please help me to create db ,table and insert data and retrieve it make it display in list.I am really in need of your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many examples of how to do it:

- [Android SQLite Basics: creating and
  using a database, and working with
  sqlite3](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)
- [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [NotePad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) in official developer's page is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Romain Guys [Shelves](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/01/19/shelves-an-open-source-android-application/) application it's a very good start point.